# Xdebug with PhpStorm and Docker

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I have docker-compose that consists of 2 services:

1. front-end application that runs on port 3000
2. back-end applications that runs on port 443

   ```
   mt_symfony:
    container_name: mt_symfony
    build:
      context: ./html
      dockerfile: dev.dockerfile
    environment:
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=192.168.220.1 remote_port=10000"
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=mt_symfony"
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - mt_network
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=0

   mt_angular:
    container_name: mt_angular
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: dev.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - mt_network
    command: ./dev.entrypoint.sh

   networks:
      mt_network:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
          driver: default
          config:
            - subnet: 192.168.220.0/28
   ```

And also in my php.ini file I have this:

```
[xdebug]
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_startup_errors = On
display_errors = On
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

mt_symfony dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6.37-apache

EXPOSE 443 80

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.5
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

COPY ./docker/php5.6-fpm.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available
RUN a2enmod headers \
    && a2enmod ssl \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && a2enconf php5.6-fpm.conf \
    && a2ensite httpd.conf
```

In PhpStorm:

1. "Build, Execution, Deployment -> Docker" shows "Connection successful"
2. "Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> CLI Interpreter" connects to docker `mt_symfony` container and detects installed Xdebug
3. "Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Xdebug -> Validate" I'm able to validate Xdebug on port 80, but it does not work at all on port 443

Comment: So .. what is your question? I personally would just ignore validation results (especially since it worked fine over plain http) because validation does not seem to work correctly with HTTPS URLs (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-51607 ticket)

Comment: xDebug does not work anyways. I use this chrome extension and enable listening in PHPStorm, but nothing happens

Comment: So it actually works.. but not always? Please collect Xdebug logs for working and not working sessions. Hopefully it will show some useful info.

Comment: It does not work at all. I've added xdebug.remote_log=/var/www/xdebug.log but the file does not appear

Comment: So... maybe it does not see your "debug me" flag? Sorry, but I see no info on how you are debugging etc. The log will be created once Xdebug sees "I need to debug this script". Without such flag it will not do anything in the log. Right now I may suggest to wither configure Xdebug to always start the debug session (for every single request) .. or add `xdebug_break();` in your code (programmatic breakpoint) and see if Xdebug will make such log file.

Comment: Second point to check: do you have something like SELinux/AppArmor or alike? It may prevent Xdebug from making any outgoing connections and writing to log file. In such case `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1` or somethign similar may be required (taken from some old thread where real OS/server was used, not container). Also (general info): https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/08/quickstart-with-docker-in-phpstorm/